# Satis - Storing a Packagist repo locally with local changes that will not be for public consumption

Tags: php, svn, composer-php, packagist, satis

I want to know if I store an existing Bundle that's on http://packagist.org in my company svn repo, do I also need to store the required packages/repos as well?

Example, the MonologBundle:

- https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/monolog-bundle ( Packagist )
- https://github.com/symfony/MonologBundle ( GIT Repo )
- https://github.com/symfony/MonologBundle/blob/master/composer.json ( JSON that shows required )

JSON required blurb:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.2",
    "symfony/monolog-bridge": ">=2.1.0,<2.3-dev",
    "symfony/dependency-injection": ">=2.1.0,<2.3-dev",
    "symfony/config": ">=2.1.0,<2.3-dev",
    "monolog/monolog": "1.*"
},
```

My company will be making local changes to this Bundle that will not be for public consumption. 
Since it will be added to our repo I wanted to know if we also have to add the required vendors/bundles/repos as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to, you can simply download the dependencies from packagist if you don't want to override those.

That said, I don't see why you would need to modify the bundle itself. It should be enough to override this or that service if needed.

Comment: Thanks again for the feedback, I do have a follow up question. My client also requires that all source code be maintained ( not outside repos ) so downloading from packagist might not be an option. I've been trying to come up with a solution using Satis but running into more questions/issues than expected. I did see that I could run my own packagist site as well but I think the same issues will still arise. Thoughts?  BTW Thanks for all the help @Seldaek! Oh and the Bundle in the example is just an example

Comment: We have similar requirements. We do not want any external dependencies in our deployment process. What we decided to do for now is to just check in the whole vendor directory after clearing .svn:s from it (we also use svn as you do). This causes some troubles with composer/subversion as it's not the recommended approach, but it can always be solved by just deleting the vendor dir contents and re-installing dependencies. A better approach would be to set up a local Satis (lightweight packagist) or packagist and fork all the packages and their requirements and add them to that repository.

Comment: @PhillPafford That's a kind of hard question right now, you can do as Clarence suggests but it's not gonna be fun.

Comment: @Clarence Yeah I'm working on the local Satis project now, thanks for the info.

Comment: @Clarence have another question that I would like your input on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13277110/composer-is-not-reading-my-local-satis-packages-json-file

Comment: Someone else was quicker on it though ;) Glad you got it sorted.